# Dart sound null safety, `!=` on null value reports false. Null check operator used on a null value

Tags: flutter, dart

I have upgraded my Flutter project to newer Dart SDK version. I have an util that can return null object, it looks like this (example):

```dart
  static Item? getCurrentItem(List<Item> list, DateTime now) {
    return list.firstWhereOrNull((item) {
      return ItemUtils.hasItemStartedStarted(item, now) &&
          !ItemUtils.didItemFinish(item, now);
    });
  }
```

This static method returns null in one instance and later on when I try to do this:

```dart
final item = ItemUtils.getCurrentItem(items, now);
if (item != null && ItemUtils.someOtherMethod(item, now) {
  ...
}
```

The code runs inside `StreamBuilder` repeatedly, I have a `Timer` set up that re-renders it periodically.

It throws error `Null check operator used on a null value`. I checked value of `item` variable and it is `null`. But `item != null` reports false, why? I checked this inside debugger, is it possible it's some stale data because of `StreamBuilder`?

This code worked before. The migration tool used `firstWhereOrNull` method instead of `.firstWhere(...., orElse: () => null)` which I'm not sure where it comes from. Could that be the issue?

Comment: How come `final item = ItemUtils.getCurrentItem(item, now);` be valid? `item` is already defined, isn't it?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, obviously it's a list of items. Fixed it.

Comment: You haven't shown us the relevant code. "Null check operator used on a null value" means that you do `x!` somewhere when `x` is `null`. Exactly what line is referenced from the stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

So actually I completely misunderstood meaning behind `!.` and `?.` syntax. From what I can tell `!.` is a cast syntax that tells Dart the object is not nullable.

For some reason I meant to use `?.` for access on nullable object. Which explains the error message. I adjusted the code to use `?.` instead of `!.` in my Flutter widget and the problem went away.

The most confusing part for me was the stack trace. The stack trace was pointing to line of code where I return `StreamBuilder` widget but did not point to usage of `!.` operator within its `builder` method. It would be nice if it actually pointed to the correct line.

Unfortunately I still don't understand why the variable `item` which was `null` did not evaluate to true with check `item != null`. I'm not sure if it's a problem with debugger but I also tried printing out the result of the expression and it was the same.